# Jasmine Unit Case for component method which has subscription returns undefined and always fails

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular-test

My component has the following method:

```
get(): void {
  this.service.get().subscribe((res) => {
    this.response = res;
  });
}
```

I have the following test case for it:

```
it('should get content ', () => {
  const currentObject = {};

  spyOn(service, 'get').and.returnValue(of(currentObject));

  component.get();

  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.response).toEqual(currentObject);

});
```

The result is always:

> Expected undefined to equal Object({  }).

There are plenty of similar questions regarding this here but for someone reason none of those work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking this could be due to the asynchronous nature of the code where `.subscribe` happens after your `expect`.

Try this to debug:

```
get(): void {
  this.service.get().subscribe((res) => {
    // !! add this log and ensure you see it first
    console.log('[get] This should happen first');
    this.response = res;
  });
}

// Test
it('should get content ', () => {
  const currentObject = {};

  spyOn(service, 'get').and.returnValue(of(currentObject));

  component.get();

  fixture.detectChanges();
  // !! add this log and ensure you see it last
  console.log('[test] This should happen last');
  expect(component.response).toEqual(currentObject);

});
```

Make sure you see `This should happen first` before `This should happen last`.

I think a potential way to fix it is maybe using `fakeAsync/tick`.

```
// wrap callback function in fakeAsync
it('should get content ', fakeAsync(() => {
  const currentObject = {};

  spyOn(service, 'get').and.returnValue(of(currentObject));

  component.get();

  fixture.detectChanges();
  // call tick() here to ensure the asynchronous subscribe runs before the expect
  tick();
  expect(component.response).toEqual(currentObject);

}));
```